(Android Studio) How to use Network Inspector rules properly?
I am using Android Studio Jellyfish, in order to test my network requests I am using Network Inspector rules in order to substitute responses from 200 to 401 for the specific query. The problem is that - in the Network Inspector I see that the response has been substituted:

But the confusing part is that in the code I also have a log
...
        val response: Response<ActiveSubscription> = repo.getActiveSubscriptionState()

        Log.e("HERE", ">>> getActiveSubscriptionState: $response")
...

the response I get here is -
>>> getActiveSubscriptionState: Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=...}

So, to sum up, even though in the Network Profiler I see that the response has been substituted, in the log I still get 200 success codes.
The question is - what am I missing here?

Your app could be the one caching an actual version of the response (HTTP 200 OK). Despite the fact that the Network Inspector shows the substituted response, your app can still possibly use the cached data hence the response may be different in Network Inspector than the app.
